# Differential Scanning Calorimetry for bacterial membranes

Tags: bacteriology, cell-membrane

I would like to study the freezing and melting of bacterial membranes and would like to use Differential Scanning Calorimetry (DSC) to obtain the glass transition temperature of the membrane. However, I am unsure where to find such protocols describing the process. Could someone please tell me how to use DSC for bacteria such as E. coli?